# How to find the email address of an external user to the domain based on their unique ID using Google People API

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-people-api

I'm using Google Apps Script to call the Google API 'https://driveactivity.googleapis.com/v2/activity:query', which returns a JSON response in the following format:

```json
{
  "activities": [
    {
      "primaryActionDetail": {
        "permissionChange": {
          "addedPermissions": [
            {
              "role": "EDITOR",
              "user": {
                "knownUser": {
                  "personName": "people/11xxxxxxxxxx6"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "actors": [
        {
          "user": {
            "knownUser": {
              "personName": "people/11xxxxxxxxxxx8",
              "isCurrentUser": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "actions": [
        {
          "detail": {
            "permissionChange": {
              "addedPermissions": [
                {
                  "role": "EDITOR",
                  "user": {
                    "knownUser": {
                      "personName": "people/115xxxxxxxxxxx6"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
```

I want to find the email address of a user outside the domain with the ID 'people/11xxxxxxxxxx6'. I've tried using the API 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people', but it only returns:

```json
{
"resourceName": "people/11xxxxxxxxxx36",
"etag": "%EgUBCS43PhoEAQIFByIMNy9sNFRaW"
}
```

Is there a way to retrieve the email address using a Google Apps Script?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution to my previous question. Instead of using the Drive Activity API, I can use the API "GET [https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive?eventName=change_user_access"](https://admin.googleapis.com/admin/reports/v1/activity/users/all/applications/drive?eventName=change_user_access%22). This API provides me with more information than the Drive Activity API. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

About `I've tried using the API 'https://people.googleapis.com/v1/people', but it only returns:`, although unfortunately, I cannot know your tested script and request, in order to retrieve the email address from the value like `people/11xxxxxxxxxx36`. How about using People API as follows?

From your tag, the sample script is Google Apps Script.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable People API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services). And, please set `resourceName`.

```js
function sample() {
  const resourceName = "people/11xxxxxxxxxx36"; // Please set your resource name.
  
  const obj = People.People.get(resourceName, { personFields: "emailAddresses" });
  const res = obj.emailAddresses.map(({ value }) => value).join(",");
  console.log(res)
}
```

- When this script is run, the email address is retrieved from `resourceName`.

#### Reference:

- [Method: people.get](https://developers.google.com/people/api/rest/v1/people/get)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your message. Just to clarify, I am able to retrieve the email addresses of users within the domain, but what I am trying to do is extract the email addresses of users who are external to the domain from the JSON response that I receive from the 'https://driveactivity.googleapis.com/v2/activity:query' API.

For example, if a user within the domain, 'user1@domain.com', shares a file with an external user, 'user2@example.com', I am able to retrieve the email address of 'user1@domain.com' using the 'People.People.get' method, but I am not able to retrieve the email address of 'user2@example.com'. The API only returns the 'etag'.

So, my question is whether there is a way to retrieve the email address of an external user using the 'people/ID' of that user.

Comment: iroic, consider moving the relevant part of this `anwer` to your question and removing the answer.